# C# How to select any character if line starts with " *:"

Tags: c#, readlines, system.io.file

I've read a Textfile using the readline method.

```
var txtfile = File.readlines([Filepath])
.where(s => s.startswith(" U:"));
```

Is there a trick to choose any letter? 
Something like this Pseudocode

```
s.startswith(" *:");
```

That's because my drive name changes continuously.
Please note that it must be the exact order of letters.
Thanks!

Comment: how many character do you expect in place of `*` in your example?

Comment: You can convert each line into a string and then check if the line contains the character or is == "*:".

Comment: just one letter instead of *

Comment: Why is there a space at the start?

Comment: Because DOS generated .txt files were generated this way, so ask MS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below regular expression.

```
.Where(s => Regex.Match(s,@"^\s.{1}:.*").Success);
```

Here is a short explanation for that regex.

`^` - start of the line

`\s` - blankspace

`.{1}` - exactly one occurrence of any character

`:` - match semicolon

`.*` - 0 or more characters

Comment: Could you explain me that?

Comment: Thank you!
It was exactly what I wanted! How can I close this question?

Comment: @V.Hunon You dont need to close the question. Since you already marked my post as answer, it is all good. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? If the lines first character is a space ( ) and the 3rd one is a colon (:). Then there can be any character in between.

```
s[0] == ' ' && s[2] == ':'
```

---

As pointed out in the comments the above wasn't 100% complete. This is a more complete line of code:

```
.where(s => s.Length >= 3 && s[0] == ' ' && s[2] == ':');
```

This code adds the `s.Length >= 3` condition which ensures that there are atleast 3 characters in the string. If you try to access a character at a non-existing index you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

---

## Performance

This is by for the most performant condition to fulfill your requirements. Additional optimizations could be done the the query but this is always much faster than Regex. This is also 100% equivalent to the Regex in the other answer, but much faster.

Comment: Although this will be the most performant and no fuss solution, it should be noted its the least robust. if there is ever a case where there is less than 3 characters, a blank line, or a `crlf` at the end of a file, this will throw an exception. so extra checks should be added

Answer (score 0):

```
s.Substring(2, 1) == ":"
```

ex:

```
" e:".Substring(2, 1) == ":" // will return true
```

Comment: This solution doesn't check if there's a space in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB's [Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator). If you're using .NET Core, you need to install [Microsoft.VisualBasic package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualBasic/). If you're using .NET Framework, you need a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

.Where(s => LikeOperator.LikeString(s, " [A-Z]:*", CompareMethod.Text))
```

Comment: For a better answer try to add some explanation to your code.

Comment: @M.R. Added explanation 